# Aplicando Django mixins y consultas con Q objects - comportamiento particular

Tags: django, sql

Tengo el siguiente mixin en el que quiero recuperar los datos del modelo de `User` con el que trabajo para colocar estos datos en diferentes vistas basadas en clases que estoy desarrollando:

```
class UserProfileDataMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileDataMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        #context['userprofile'] = user.profile
        if user.is_authenticated():
            context['userprofile'] = user.profile
        return context
```

Entonces, tengo la siguiente vista basada en clase en la cual deseo buscar usuarios acorde a la coincidencia con su `username` y `full_name`  campos del modelo `User` que trabajo.

```
class SearchView(UserProfileDataMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        qs = None
        if query:
            qs = User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__icontains=query) |
                Q(full_name__icontains=query)
            )
        context = {"users": qs}

        return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

Cuando yo estoy heredando desde `UserProfileDataMixin` este mixin me da la posibilidad de tener la variable de contexto `userprofile` para pasarla a mi template `search.html` el cual hereda desde `layout.html` template en el cual efectuo la siguiente validación:

**search.html template**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
```

**layout.html template**

```
{% if userprofile %}
    I put the data of user by example:
    avatar, username, full_name, and menu options to my app.   
{% endif %}
```

Hasta aquí, todo bien, pero mi vista basada en clase `SearchView` no aplica el mixin `UserProfileDataMixin`, digo esto, porque no puedo obtener los datos de usuario sobre mi template los cuales vienen de `layout.html`.

Cuando despliego la plantilla de búsqueda de usuarios, obtengo que mis datos de usuario no aparecen en el top menu o encabezado en donde deseo que aparezcan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He cambiado ligeramente mi vista basada en clase `SearchView` sobreescribiendo el método `get_queryset` en lugar de el método `get`

```
class SearchView(UserProfileDataMixin, ListView):
        template_name = 'search.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        qs = None
        if query:
            qs = User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__icontains=query) |
                Q(full_name__icontains=query)
            )
        context = {"users": qs}
        return render(self.request, "search.html", context)
```

Y mi vista basada en clase `SearchView` aplica el mixin `UserProfileDataMixin` porque ahora puedo obtener los datos de usuario  desde `layout.html` sobre mi template de `search.html` on my template.

Ahora, aparece en mi top header menu, estos datos que son los que me trae el  `UserProfileDataMixin`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero entonces, ahora, tengo el inconveniente de que mi consulta Q de buscar usuarios no funciona

¿Cuál es la razón, para que mi mixin `UserProfileDataMixin` no sea aplicado o heredado en mi vista basada en clase `SearchView` cuando sobreescribo el método `get`, pero sí cuando sobreescribo  el método `get_queryset`?

¿Por qué esto elimina el efecto de mi consulta Q ?
¿Cuándo debería usar get y cuándo usar get_queryset?

En [este post, hay una respuesta muy ilustrativa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36950584/2773461) y acorde a ello, pienso que el m[etodo get_queryset es la mejor opción para mi caso, pero no se que estoy haciendo mal que mi consulta con el objeto Q de búsqueda de usuarios no es ejecutada del todo bien.

Por qué con `get_queryset` mi consulta no es ejecutada de la misma manera como cuando uso `get`?

Comment: Parece que tienes una confusión en como funcionan las Vistas Basadas en Clases y sus métodos, te recomendaría leer bien primero que métodos tienes disponibles y la función de cada uno, no es muy complicado de entender y encontrarás una solución rápida y sencilla a tu tarea, te dejaré [esta](https://ccbv.co.uk/) página que en su momento me ayudó bastante para aprender como funcionaban las vistas basadas en clases

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cuál es la razón, para que mi mixin UserProfileDataMixin no sea
>   aplicado o heredado en mi vista basada en clase SearchView cuando
>   sobreescribo el método get, pero sí cuando sobreescribo el método
>   get_queryset?

Primero debes estudiar como se ejecuta el código de tu clase genérica. por lo que veo en el código estas utilizando mal los métodos heredados. Por ejemplo:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
    allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()

    if not allow_empty:
        # When pagination is enabled and object_list is a queryset,
        # it's better to do a cheap query than to load the unpaginated
        # queryset in memory.
        if self.get_paginate_by(self.object_list) is not None and hasattr(self.object_list, 'exists'):
            is_empty = not self.object_list.exists()
        else:
            is_empty = len(self.object_list) == 0
        if is_empty:
            raise Http404(_("Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.") % {
                'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
            })
    context = self.get_context_data()
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

el código anterior es el get de la clase **BaseListView** de django. si te fijas en la penúltima línea te das cuenta que el contexto lo sacan del método **context = get_context_data()** mientras que tu en tu método get lo creas directamente. **context = {"users": qs}** lo que ocasiona que el método que creaste en tu mixin nunca sea llamado. y es por eso que no funciona cuando sobreescribes el método get.

ahora cuando implementas el método **get_query_set** se ejecuta el mixin porque se ejecuta es la clase de django donde se llama al get_context_data. Pero sigue sin funcionar porque estas retornando un objeto del tipo response. mientras que el método debe retornar es un queryset. tu clase debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
class SearchView(UserProfileDataMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        qs = Users.objects
        if query:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(username__icontains=query) |
                Q(full_name__icontains=query)
            )
        return qs
```

no necesitas incluir directamente la lista de usuarios en el contexto la clase ListView lo hace. es accesible por el nombre **'%s_list' % model_name** por lo que si es Users la clase la tendrías en user_list. si quieres cambiarle el nombre puedes usar la variable **context_object_name** en la definición de tu clase.

Comment: Entiendo la muy gran explicacion que me envias, y si, acorde a lo que me dices, al no usar `get_context_data` con el metodo `get` o al sacar por mi cuenta la variable `context` y enviarla, evidentemente se ignora el `UserProfileDataMixin` el cual me trae los datos de usuario que necesito precisamente a través de un `get_context_data`. Gracias por orientarme en comprender ese comportamiento, porque lo estaba pasando por alto o no conocia como analizar la situación. Pero sucede que retorno un queryset usando el método `get_queryset` como me dices y el comportamiento de mi búsqueda es igual,

Comment: Lo que he intentado acorde a los elementos que me das en tu análisis es que de todas formas el `get_context_data()` juega un rol importante, para la herencia del mixin, asi que me dió por intentar efectuar la consulta `Q` en un `get_context_data()` y enviar ese queryset al template y retornarlo también como me decías y funciona. El mixin `UserProfileDataMixin` es tomado y la consulta me retorna los objetos `Q` deseados. [En este gist](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/a71caab2968851433bfb3ad1131eb603) se ve como finalmente ha quedado mi vista basada en clase `SearchView`.

Comment: No se si mi enfoque es el adecuado o muy facilista o si exista una mejor forma de hacerlo desde la perspectiva de los metodos `get` o `get_queryset()`